# Conditional use of std::lock_guard

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, locking, conditional-statements

I have a function where the statement `foo` should be executed under `lock_guard` but only when a pointer to a `mutex` object has been provided to the function as a parameter. Otherwise `foo` does not have to be *protected by  `lock_guard`*.

I cannot *use* the `lock_guard` within an `if` because the lock will be released immediately when the `if` block ends.

so, this code is nonsense:

```
bar( std::mutex * optionalMutex = nullptr )
{
   ...
   if ( nullptr != optionalMutex ) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockScope( *optionalMutex );
   }          <- Here the lock ends

   foo...     <- foo is not protected when optionalMutex was provided
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
bar( std::mutex * optionalMutex = nullptr )
{
   ...
   nullptr == optionalMutex ? 0 : std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockScope( *optionalMutex );

   // this scope should be protected by lock_guard when optionalMutex was provided

   foo...
}
```

More or less, the only one possible solution for me is to repeat  `foo`:

```
bar( std::mutex * optionalMutex = nullptr )
{
   ...
   if ( nullptr != optionalMutex ) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockScope( *optionalMutex );
      foo...
   }  else {
      foo...
   }
}
```

The compiler `gcc 4.9.3` does not compile the 2nd example and complains: `error: expected primary-expression before 'lockScope'`. **Update:** Superlokkus explained in his answer why.

But I do want to avoid any code duplicates and therefore also the duplicate `foo`.

**My question:**

Is there an *elegant* way how to implement this problem and **not** to use duplicate `foo`. I know, I could use a lambda function to *group* `foo` but I am curious if there is an another solution.

Comment: This looks a bit scary tbh :)

Comment: Are you trying to use functionality foo with different mutexes or just in a thread safe or a non threadsafe manner ?

Comment: I guess people are concerned that this is a XY Question (  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 ): Does bar something where data races can occur? Why is the mutex optional? Because it could already be held? Or do you have reader/writer?

Comment: @Superlokkus Why is `mutex` optional: `foo()` is a) running with a thread member variable [provided as parameter] and b) with a variable which is *controlling* all other threads and therefore it must be protected by `mutex`. But how ever, your answer solved it and is already accepted.

Comment: I tried if (mutex != nullptr) {mutex->lock()} then realized this would be a deadlock:D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this one?

```
void bar(std::mutex * optionalMutex = nullptr)
{
        auto lockScope = (optionalMutex == nullptr) ? 
                           std::unique_lock<std::mutex>() 
                         : std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(*optionalMutex);
}
```

Explanation: Your compiler had trouble with your prior statement because, you can not suddenly change the type of the ternary `?` expression; i.e. the literal `0` is not a `std::lock_guard` and vice versa. So I changed the two branches to the same type, here `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` because `lock_guard` isn't designed be used without a valid mutex. But still prefer `std::lock_guard` over `std::unique_lock` in the simpler cases, because it will make your code more readable.

Also your statement wasn't viable for the compiler, i.e. even syntactical correct, because the variable lockScope would only have existed in one branch.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for! No *dummy* `mutex` and very elegant! Accepted and upvoted!

Comment: To increase the elegance for your code, have a look at boost optional library - this will let you get rid of ugly nullptr checks

Comment: Of course one could also write `!optionalMutex` instead of `optionalMutex == nullptr`, or even better, inverse the whole conditional.

Comment: Or alternatively if you have more complex conditions that would look bad with ternary ?:
`std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock;
if (optionalMutex)
  lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{*optionalMutex);`

Comment: @ipapadop While I can relate to your intention, ;-) , I have 2 problems with your explicit if approach:
A) You have two statements which means A1) It's prone that some college, or even you and me, will eventually displace it in a rush (see Apple goto Bug)  or even "optimize" it out A2) You don't have that sweet RAII semantics anymore, i.e. less readable B) You first create a empty unique lock and then, in most cases, you create another one and forget the old one -> Performance, so even more prone to A1)

Comment: Here's an alternative using `std::optional`. It benefits from only using automatic storage. `using opt_guard = std::optional<std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>; opt_guard guard{dont_guard ? opt_guard{std::nullopt} : opt_guard{my_lock}};`

Comment: @RichardForrest My solution also only uses automatic storage. Although in general in recommend the use of `std::optional` I don't see any benefit of `std::optional<std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>` over `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`. Indeed it would put off readers of the code maybe. And the fact he uses a `std::mutex *` doesn't say anything about the storage class. It's just that you don't want to copy mutexes. Could be a pointer to an auto or static stored mutex.

Comment: One more thing: I found that compiler can optimize `unique_lock` method but cannot optimize `lock_guard` + dummy `mutex` method.

Comment: @YouJiacheng only seems logical since `lock_guard` always locks a mutex, and the dummy mutex is still a real mutex. Just a nonsensical one.

Answer (score 13):

What you really have is two functions, one that locks, and one that doesn't. The first one can call the second:

```
void bar() {
    // whatever
}

void bar(std::mutex* mtx) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockScope(*mtx);
    bar();
}
```

Comment: What's `auto` going to resolve to?  Wouldn't it be an `std::mutex` (and what you really want is a `std::lock_guard`)?  And shouldn't the second bar really take the `std::mutex` by reference (stylistic, I suppose, but enforces that you don't get a `nullptr` passed to you)?  If the caller didn't have a mutex handy, it should be calling `bar()` anyway.

Comment: @AndreKostur - yes, of course, `auto` was silly. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreKostur - yes, it probably should take a reference, not a pointer. The point of the example, though, is to show the connection with the original code, not to advise on style.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution for me at all. I did not mentioned `foo` is a function. I wanted to use it as a synonym for code. In this code there are used local variables defined above the mutex lock which cannot be used in your suggestion. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1):

I have only this solution. Using a dummy `mutex` object:

The code is:

```
bar( std::mutex * optionalMutex = nullptr )
{
   ...
   std::mutex dummyMutex;
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockScope( optionalMutex ? *optionalMutex, dummyMutex );

   foo...     <- NOW foo is protected when optionalMutex was provided
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a minor gripe but you can avoid passing the the raw pointer by letting the caller pass a std::unique_lock instead:

```
bar( std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockScope )
{
    if(lockScope.mutex())
    {
        lockScope.lock();
        //do things
    }
}
```

This seems like a more clear expression of the interface and reduces potential for abuse.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly trivial to implement your own version of lock_guard which takes a pointer to a mutex rather than a reference.

```
template <typename MutexT>
class conditional_lock_guard
{
private:

    MutexT* const m_mtx;

public:

    explicit conditional_lock_guard(MutexT* mtx) :
        m_mtx{ mtx }
    {
        if (m_mtx != nullptr)
        {
            m_mtx->lock();
        }
    }

    ~conditional_lock_guard() noexcept
    {
        if (m_mtx != nullptr)
        {
            m_mtx->unlock();
        }
    }

    conditional_lock_guard(const conditional_lock_guard&) = delete;
    conditional_lock_guard& operator=(const conditional_lock_guard&) = delete;

    bool owns_lock() const noexcept
    {
        return m_mtx != nullptr;
    }

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept
    {
        return owns_lock();
    }

    MutexT* mutex() const noexcept
    {
        return m_mtx;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Superlockus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38611830/4382581) is good enough, but I am wondering why you did not simply write it like that:

```
bar( std::mutex * optionalMutex = nullptr )
{
   if (optionalMutex)
      optionalMutex->lock():

   foo...

   if (optionalMutex)
      optionalMutex->unlock():
}
```

`lock_guard` and `unique_lock` are convenient but not the only way.